# I am trying to create a table from a jsfiddle example but its not working ANGULAR.JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a table that I found here

but I have to integrate it to my solutions and code and when I do that, I get these wonky chracters but no error.
my code is here

please see the image below.

I am trying to have this

Comment: You never create the variable 'test'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its working fine http://jsfiddle.net/ipsjolly/6zydf/ you can change the data in you want to enter in js section

Comment: yes I know it works there but my other fiddle link doesnt work ..and I want that one to work